# Here i am getting error so help me

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
     $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","telephasic");
     if(isset($_GET['role']))
     {
        $role1=$_GET['role'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$role1'";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_object($query))
        {
            $role_var=$row->role;
            if($role_var=='1')
            {
                $role_state="NULL";
            } else {
                $role_state="0";
            }
            $update=mysql_query("update register set status='$role_state' where id='$role1' ");
            if($update)
            {
               header("Location:admin.php");
            } else {
               echo mysql_error();
            }
       }
?>
<?php } ?>
```

I am getting error here so help me please

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_fetch_object() in C:\xampp\htdocs\telephasic\action.php:7 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\telephasic\action.php on
>   line 7

Comment: which PHP version?

Comment: You should make a query to database first only then fetch

Comment: you should use `mysqli_fetch_object` instead of `mysql_fetch_object`, [here is doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Comment: Also if you are using mysqli for connection don't use mysql after

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud That alone won't make the code work. There's still `mysql_query()` and `mysql_error()`.

Comment: yes you are right @kerbholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
   <?php
         $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","telephasic");
         if(isset($_GET['role']))
         {
            $role1=$_GET['role'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$role1'";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query); // u need to execute query first!!
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
            {
                $role_var=$row->role;
                if($role_var=='1')
                {
                    $role_state="NULL";
                } else {
                    $role_state="0";
                }
                $update=mysqli_query($conn, "update register set status='$role_state' where id='$role1' ");
                if($update)
                {
                   header("Location:admin.php");
                } else {
                   echo mysqli_error();
                }
           }
    ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\telephasic\action.php on line 8

Comment: Try again, i edited the code!

Comment: yes it works thanks alot

Comment: can you please help me?